# Passing jira description as html code

Tags: jira, python-jira

I am trying to understand how can I pass html code to be rendered in python description field using [python-jira](https://jira.readthedocs.io).

If anyone can explain what is told in [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-enable-html-in-jira-text-fields-771895067.html) paragraph 4  and adding simple working example I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you will be able to enter text in the field with HTML in it. For example, you will be able to enter text like this one: `{html}<a href="http://www.atlassian.com">Click here</a> to see the <b>Atlassian</b> website.{html}` and it will be rendered as HTML like this:

[Click here](http://www.atlassian.com) to see the **Atlassian** website.

For more information, please refer to the [documentation of HTML Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/html-macro-38273085.html).